# Check if active carousel item has a attribute with a value of 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using boostrap carousel:

```
<div class="carousel-item slide" data-llp-is-question="0"></div>
<div class="carousel-item slide" data-llp-is-question="0"></div>
<div class="carousel-item slide" data-llp-is-question="0"></div>
<!-- Two Questions together -->
<div class="carousel-item quest" data-llp-is-question="1"></div>
<div class="carousel-item quest" data-llp-is-question="1"></div>
<div class="carousel-item slide" data-llp-is-question="0"></div>
<div class="carousel-item slide" data-llp-is-question="0"></div>
<div class="carousel-item slide" data-llp-is-question="0"></div>
<div class="carousel-item quest" data-llp-is-question="1"></div>
<div class="carousel-item slide" data-llp-is-question="0"></div>
```

Above you can see that I am setting a `data` tag on the carousel item as well as a specific class.

What I need to do is have a function which fires every time a slide is moved on to see if the item is a question `data-llp-is-question="1"` and if so hide the navigation elements and some other divs.

My Function:

```
function checkIfQuestionSlide()
{
    var $this;
    $this = $("#moduleSlideContainer");
    if ($("#moduleSlideContainer .carousel-inner .carousel-item").is(":visible") && $("#moduleSlideContainer .carousel-inner .carousel-item").data('llp-is-question')) {
        console.log('Is a question');
        $this.children(".section-previous").hide();
        $this.children(".section-continue").hide();
    }else{
        console.log('Is not a question');
        $this.children(".section-previous").show();
        $this.children(".section-continue").show();     
    }
};
```

Which I call on `Document.Load` and also here:

```
$('#moduleSlideContainer').on('slide.bs.carousel','', checkIfQuestionSlide);
```

The issue is I always get the result of the item not being a question.

Please, can someone point out where I am being an idiot and show me the right path ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will always return true since at least one slide is visible at any given time (this is how `is` works):

```
$("#moduleSlideContainer .carousel-inner .carousel-item").is(":visible")
```

and this will always return 0 (the data for *first* matching item):

```
$("#moduleSlideContainer .carousel-inner .carousel-item").data('llp-is-question')
```

This explains why you get same result each time. The correct solution is to [read the manual](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#events) and use the slide event:

```
$("#moduleSlideContainer").on("slide.bs.carousel", function(e) {
  var $slide = $(e.relatedTarget);
  if ($slide.data("llp-is-question")) {
    console.log(e.relatedTarget, "is a question");
  } else {
    console.log(e.relatedTarget, "is not question");
  }
});
```

Comment: That's great thanks, however, it doesn't pick up the first question if there are two together can you help with that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by two together? Do you have two slideshows? Ortwo slides visible at a time?

Comment: I have updated my HTML in the question. There are two items which are designated and questions next to each other, the first doesn't get picked up but the second does.

Answer (score 1):

the bootstrap carousel should have a property called relatedTarget you can use (depending on the version you are using)

```
$(".carousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', (e) ->
    console.log(e.relatedTarget);
)
```

relatedTarget is the element that is coming into view. hope this helps.